# How to set user specific settings to Session

Tags: octobercms

I am developing a custom plugin that adds account selection dropdown to the backend header. Dropdown values are dependent on the currently logged in user and the active selection is saved in the session.

Currently I'm listening for the `backend.user.login` event in the plugins `boot()` method. And when fired, I save the first account ID as the active one

```
Session::put('user.account', $user->accounts()->first()->id)
```

Instead on listening for the login event, I'd like to always check if the default value is set and if not, set it.

Where should I do that?

Note that when the `boot()` method is called, the backend user in not yet initialized and cannot be fetched with `BackendAuth::getUser();`

Comment: What's the problem with listening to that event?

Comment: The problem is not with the event itself.
I'd like to set the session variable in the boot() method and not listen for the login event

Comment: For getting user you can use App::before
`public function boot() {
    \App::before(function() {
        // Here BackendAuth::getUser() is already initialized
    }
}`